# Wrong encoding with GWT, restygwt, Spring MVC, JSON. ISO-8859-1 vs. utf-8?

Tags: json, gwt, rest, spring-mvc, utf-8

I don't really know WHERE to problem is, but I can tell the following:

First I used GWT RequestBuilder:

```
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "/myRESTResource/test");
rb.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
rb.setRequestData("");
rb.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        Window.alert(response.getText());
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        Window.alert(exception);
    }
});
rb.send();
```

My Spring Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myRESTResource")
public class TranslationController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/{param}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String get(@PathVariable("param") String param, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // get some data and output it as JSON
    }
}
```

In Chrome-Browser I can see the response returned with `Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`. The `Window.alert()` was fine.

Now I wanted to switch to restygwt. I am using `Resource`:

```
Resource r = new Resource("myRESTResource/test");
r.get().send(new JsonCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Method method, JSONValue response) {
        Window.alert(response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
        Window.alert(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});
```

Here my Spring Controller returns with `Content-type: application/json`. The `Window.alert()` is fine for ASCII-Characters, but everything special becomes a black box with a questionmark inside. The problem occures in GWT Development Mode (Eclipse 4.2 with integrated Jetty) and also deployed on an external Tomcat 7.

If I use restygwt and put

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

inside my Spring Controller the `Window.alert()` displays the data as expected.

It's clear that I don't want to write `response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");` inside every Controller-method.

I hope there's a simple way to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple:

Just say the restygwt `Resource` which encoding it wants to get from the server:

`Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8`

or:

`Accept: application/json; charset=iso-8859-1`

Code example:

```
HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
header.put(Resource.HEADER_ACCEPT, Resource.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON+"; charset=utf-8");

Resource r = new Resource("myRESTResource/test", header);
r.get().send(new JsonCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Method method, JSONValue response) {
        Window.alert(response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
        Window.alert(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});
```

Spring will automatically return the expected encoding!

Answer (score 0):

Yo don't seem to be generating json from the server.
You are just returning a String.

Try putting this in your Service:

`@RequestMapping(value="/{param}", method=RequestMethod.GET**, produces = "application/json"**)`

You can use a tool like RestClient to verify that the server is actually returning a json or not.

Comment: As you can see I've already answered my own question ;-) The solution is pretty simple: Spring will return what you request. This means if your HTTP request header specifies that you want to receive `application/json` then Spring will do so. But your solution will also work.